# How to calculate the accumulation of a signal in the z domain

Tags: z-transform

I was trying to study for a future DSP exam and while reviewing some questions i was faced with the following:

> **Question 12:** Two right-sided discrete-time signals $x \! \left[ n \right]$ and $y \! \left[ n \right]$ are related in the following manner:
> $$ y \! \left[ n \right]  = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{n} x \! \left[ k \right].$$
> The $z$-transform of $y \! \left[ n \right]$ is $\frac{z^{3} - z^{2} + 1}{z \left( z - 1 \right)^{2}}$. Then ...

I am unsure of how to do the following, computing the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $x \! \left[ k \right]$ if anyone could give me any insight here or the reasoning to adopt here.

Comment: Please avoid adding unnecessary pictures and use $\LaTeX$ to typeset your Maths. As for your question, a hint is to think of another way to represent the running sum of $x[k]$. It involves a certain very useful operator and the unit step function $u[n]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hidden the answer to this question under spoilers to motivate the OP to think about the hint given in my comment above:

> ... think of another way to represent the running sum of $x[k]$. It involves a certain very useful operator and the unit step function $u[n]$.

> The key to solving this question is to realize that convolution of a right-sided sequence  $x[n]$ with the unit step function $u[n]$ can resemble an accumulator under *certain* conditions. The unit step function $u[n]$ is defined as 1 for $n \geq 0$ and 0 for $n < 0$. The convolution sum $y[n] = x[n] * u[n]$ is defined as: $$y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} x[k] \cdot u[n-k]$$

> Since $u[n-k] = 1$ for $n-k \geq 0$ (which is $k \leq n$) and 0 otherwise, the convolution sum simplifies to: $$y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} x[k]$$

> This sum is essentially an accumulator for the sequence $x[n]$ up to index $n$, accumulating the values of $x[n]$ for all indices up to and including $n$. However, it's important to note that this accumulator-like behavior is only valid when $x[n]$ is a *right-sided* sequence starting from some **finite** index $n_0$ (where $n_0$ could be negative, zero, or positive). If $x[n]$ has infinite support in both directions, then this interpretation as an accumulator is not correct.

> Now that we have established the fact that $y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{n} x[k] = x[n] \ast u[n]$ we can simply use the properties of the $\mathcal{Z}$-Transform, namely: $$\mathrm{\mathit{x}_{\mathrm{1}}\mathrm{\left(\mathit{n}\right)}*\mathit{x}_{\mathrm{2}}\mathrm{\left(\mathit{n}\right)}\overset{\mathcal{Z}}{\leftrightarrow}\mathit{X}_{\mathrm{1}}\mathrm{\left(\mathit{z}\right)}\mathit{X}_{\mathrm{2}}\mathrm{\left(\mathit{z}\right)};\:\:\mathrm{ROC}\:\mathrm{=}\:\mathit{R}_{\mathrm{1}}\cap\mathit{R}_{\mathrm{2}} }$$

> For our case we have $y[n] = x[n] \ast u[n] \overset{\mathcal{Z}}\longrightarrow Y(z) = X(z)\cdot U(z)$ where $Y(z)$ is given in the question and $U(z)$ is:$$U(z) = \frac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$$ which gives us: $$X(z) = \left(\frac{z^{3} - z^{2} + 1}{z \left( z - 1 \right)^{2}} \right) \cdot (1-z^{-1})$$ with the appropriate ROC.